# Zeta of 3, why cant we get the value the zeta of odd n?

Tags: riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

$f(x) = \pi^2 - x ^2$ on $|x|<\pi$ and $f(x+2\pi)=f(x)$.

I did find its Fourier expansion

$f(x)=\frac{2}{3}\pi^2$+$\sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{4}{n^2}(-1)^{n+1}\cos x$

And by putting $x=\pi$, I got the zeta of $2$ , $\zeta(2) = \sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Similarly, if i try do this process about $f(x) = \pi^4-x^4$ then I could get the value  $\zeta(4)=\frac{\pi^4}{90}$ if so, why can't I get the value of $\zeta(3)$ with $f(x) = \pi^3 - x ^3$ ?
I wonder the principle that I can't do in general, why can't we get the value the zeta of odd $n$?

Comment: It is suspected that $\zeta(2k+1)$ is algebraically independent of $\pi$, though mathematicians have other worries.

Comment: Is it proved? Where can I see the data on it?

Comment: As I said, it has not been proved, only suspected. $\zeta(3)$ is sometimes known as Apéry's constant and has some applications in quantum mechanics.

Comment: "why cant i get the value of $\zeta(3)$ with $f(x) = \pi^3 - x ^3$ ?" How did you try? How did it fail?

Comment: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02864395

Comment: The question should be, why can we find an expression for $n$ even? ...

Answer (score 8):

Of course I don't have a proof that $\zeta(3)$ is a completely new constant, but I think this might be interesting :

- Let $\displaystyle f(z) = \frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)}$ and $\displaystyle g(z) = \frac{d^2}{dz^2} \log(\Gamma(z))$ [$= \psi'(z)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

  Using [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)) (and showing $\Gamma(z)$ has no zeros) you get that 
  $$f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(z+ n)^2}, \qquad\quad g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(z+n)^2}$$
- Differentiating : $\displaystyle f^{(k)}(z) = (-1)^k \frac{(2+k)!}{2}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(z+ n)^{2+k}}$ so that
  $$f^{(2k+1)}(1/2) = 0, \qquad f^{(2k)}(1/2) = (2+2k)!(2^{2k+2}-1)\zeta(2k+2)$$

$$g^{(k)}(1/2) = \frac{(2+k)!}{2}(2^{k+2}-1)\zeta(k+2)$$

- Finally, evaluating $\zeta(2k)$ is as easy as evaluating the derivatives of  $\sin(\pi z)$ at $z=1/2$,

  while evaluating $\zeta(2k+1)$ is as hard as evaluating the derivatives of  $\Gamma(z)$ at $z=1/2$.

Comment: Thanks for the neat and compact answer, but how is Liouville's theorem used?

Comment: @Ranc [there is a derivation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1959285/sum-k-infty-infty-frac1k-alpha2-frac-pi2-sin2-pi-alpha/1960134#1960134) of $f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(z+n)^2}$. For $g(z)$ it is a little more complicated, look at a proof of the [Weierstrass product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Weierstrass.27s_definition) for $\Gamma(s)$)