# Deriving an accelerated sum for the Weierstrass $\wp$-function

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-functions

This formula was shown in *A Course in Modern Analysis - Whittaker, Watson* as an exercise

[image]

How could this be proven? My guess is that it involves summing the partial fraction version of $\wp$ over all multiples of $\omega_1$.

Comment: $\wp$ is defined by a double sum. This is what one gets if one sums over one of the variables

Comment: Thanks! How would that summation be performed? How would we end up with cosec^2 and -1/3 and so on.

Comment: There are well-known formulae for sums like $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty 1/(w-n)^2$.

Comment: How are they derived?

Comment: $1/(\sin^2 z)=-(\cot z)'$ and the partial fraction decomposition of the tangent is well known, so just differentiate term by term

Comment: Look for questions like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1959285).

Comment: What is the meaning of the dash at the 2nd summation?