# The function $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {(n + x \cdot i)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be the complex-valued function defined by
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {(n + x \cdot i)^2}$$
in the real variable $x$, being $i$ the imaginary unit.

Clearly,
$$f(0)=\frac {\pi^2} 6$$

Further,
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {n^2-x^2} {(n^2+x^2)^2} - 2x \cdot i \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {n} {(n^2+x^2)^2}$$
therefore
$$f(-x)=\overline{f(x)}$$

If one plots the values of $f(x)$ in the complex plane, at a first look the result is quite similar to a circle $(|x| \lt 100)$

[image]

But a closer analysis shows the following behavior for large values of $|x|\;(20 \lt |x| \lt 1000)$

[image]

**I ask if there are theoretical references that explain the graphs obtained.**

Comment: For what it’s worth, $f(x)=\psi^{(1)} (1+i x)$ where $\psi^{(1)}$ is the trigamma function.

Comment: @KStarGamer  Many thanks.

Comment: Using https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1959285/42969 you can compute $2 \operatorname{Re} f(x) = 1/x^2- \pi^2/\sinh^2(\pi x) \ge 0$. Which means that the second graph suffers from rounding errors.

Comment: The $f$ you describe here is the well-studied [Hurwitz zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function) for argument $s = 2$ and $a = 1 + i x$. About the characteristics of this precise graph, I don't know if it is studied.

Comment: Can you show what precise error bounds you use? Typically one would use packages such as [Nemo](https://github.com/Nemocas/Nemo.jl/) or [Arb](https://github.com/fredrik-johansson/arb/).