# Why is it so hard to find a closed form for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p}$ converges for $p>1$; I have known this result since I took calculus in my freshman year. It is also known that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6} \text{ and } \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4}=\frac{\pi^4}{90}$$

I learned a few years later--while taking a history and philosophy of mathematics course of all places--that the precise value for which the series converges for $p=3$ is still unknown. Doing some brief investigation--using Wolfram|Alpha and Wikipedia--it appears that the result is defined in terms of the Riemann zeta function, i.e. $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}=\zeta(3)\approx 1.2020569...$$

I have been told that a closed form has not been found. My question is why the mechanisms we have developed that enable us to find a closed form in the previous two cases fail in the third case? What it is that makes the $p=3$ case much more difficult? Is there even a closed form for the $p=3$ case, and for that matter, for all odd-numbered cases? I have attempted to ask one of my math professors this question, but I did not quite understand the explanation at the time.

For added context, I am currently doing an undergraduate degree in statistics. As such, I have only taken two semesters of real analysis, and one semester of complex analysis. I also feel like this question might have been have been asked on this site before; if so, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Search "Apery" on this site. Your exact question was asked by someone. I will point to it if I find it.

Comment: The question is somewhat backwards: what is surprising is that one can find closed forms for the other series! There is no reason at all for a series, no matter how nice the general term, has a sum with a nice closed form.

Comment: That one can solve the even cases can be traced back to [the fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem#Euler.27s_approach) that when you plug $\pi$ into the Taylor expansion of $\sin(x)$ you should get 0. There is nothing similar for the odd cases.

Comment: [This thread](https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/math/comments/409x5g/is_anyone_aware_of_workspapers_anything_put/?client=ms-android-samsung) may help you.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez You're right of course, but how does one show that a sum doesn't have a closed form (in terms of "usual" operations on well known numbers)?

Comment: @3-in-441 there is no *proof* that $\zeta(3)$ doesn't have a closed form in terms of more familiar numbers, since barely anything is known about that number other than its irrationality.  We can't prove it's algebraically independent of $e$ or $\pi$, since that would in particular imply $\zeta(3)$ is transcendental, which goes waaaay beyond what is known.

Comment: @KCd Clearly! I meant "a sum" as in "are there any techniques for showing that a closed form of a sum (or whatever) doesn't exist." Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: See this [similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1947787/zeta-of-3-why-cant-we-get-the-value-the-zeta-of-odd-n/1978727#1978727) we can compute a closed-form of $\zeta(2n)$ because it is the derivative of $\cos(z)/\sin(z)$ at $z=1/2$, but $\zeta(2n+1)$ is the derivative of $\Gamma'(z)/\Gamma(z)$ at $z=1/2$ which is much more complicated

Comment: Similar mysteries abound in Mathematics. For instance, the existence of even perfect numbers is found in Euclid's books (the proof is elementary), and that of odd ones is still elusive.

Answer (score 2):

Roger Apéry proved in 1978 that $\zeta(3)=\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-3}$ is irrational, however the irrationality of $\displaystyle\frac{\zeta(3)}{\pi^3}$ is still an open problem. No closed form for its value is currently known.

There are however some formulas expressing $\zeta(3)$ (and other odd zeta values) in terms of powers of $\pi$, but these are not closed forms. The most well known ones are due to Plouffe and Borwein & Bradley:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\zeta(3)&=\frac{7\pi^3}{180}-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3(e^{2\pi n}-1)},\\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3\,\binom {2n}n} &= -\frac{4}{3}\,\zeta(3)+\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{2\cdot 3^2}\,\left(\zeta(2, \tfrac{1}{3})-\zeta(2,\tfrac{2}{3}) \right).
\end{aligned}
$$

Moreover, in [this Math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157040/a-new-formula-for-aperys-constant-and-other-zetas) we have:

$$
\frac{3}{2}\,\zeta(3) = \frac{\pi^3}{24}\sqrt{2}-2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^3(e^{\pi k\sqrt{2}}-1)}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^3(e^{2\pi k\sqrt{2}}-1)}.
$$

You can also check out [this paper by Vepstas](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0609775v4.pdf), which provides a nice generalization to some of these identities.

Answer (score 1):

It can be shown that $\frac{\sin \pi x}{\pi x}=\prod_{k\ge 1}(1-\frac{x^2}{k^2})$.  The left-hand side's Maclaurin series can be used to write $\pi^{2n}$ in terms of $\zeta(2k),\,1\le k\le n$. There is no similar theoretical treatment of $\zeta(m)$ for odd $m\ge 3$.

Comment: An interesting attempt to extend Euler's method to $\zeta(3)$ can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1459709/can-this-approximate-closed-form-of-aperys-constant-zeta3-be-improved/